# How to solve this error? xhr.js:178 GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=Tesla 403

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I get this error in console.

```
xhr.js:178 GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=river 403
```

I created a separate component for later use of this api:

```
const KEY = "mykeyas23d2sdffa12sasd12dfasdfasdfasdf";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
  params: {
    part: "snippet",
    maxResults: 5,
    key: KEY,
  },
});
```

then in `App.js` called:

```
import youtube from "../apis/youtube";

class App extends React.Component {
  handleQuery = (term) => {
    youtube.get("/search", {
      params: {
        q: term,
      },
    });
  };
  ...
}
```

However, when I put them together. Like:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleQuery = (term) => {
    console.log(term);
    axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
      params: {
        part: "snippet",
        maxResults: 5,
        key: "mykeyas23d2sdffa12sasd12dfasdfasdfasdf",
        q: term,
      },
    });
  };

  render() { ... }
}

export default App;
```

This above code works fine, but first doesn't. How do I solve the error with that separate component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `axios` made some changes from version `0.18x` to `0.19x` and made a change on the feature that enables to send an instance of axios with `axios.create()`.

This means that you cannot export your default axios config and import it, at least until feature releases. For you, this resulted in a `403` error, because axios did not have prior knowledge of the config defined in `../api/youtube` due to the modifications I mentioned.

This is according to this github issue: [axios.create() can't not handle params](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2230)

A solution to your problem would be to define your config file in, say `api/config` as:

```
export const config = {
  baseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
  params: {
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 5,
    key: YOUR_API_KEY,
  },
};
```

And use it in your `App.js` as:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { config } from './apis/config';

class App extends React.Component {
   handleQuery = async (term) => {
      console.log(term);
      config['params'] = { ...config['params'], q: term };
      const response = await axios.get('/search', config);
      console.log(response);
   };
   return (...)
}
```

*What I did was to concatenate to the imported `config` the `q` value. This is done easily in javascript using {...config, key:value}. The `...` mean: copy everything from config as it was before.

**EDIT**

Your config object should look like this (after setting the `q` parameter):
[image: Config object]

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote, to be precise copy paste it, but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure your API key is valid? Did you register it accordingly?
Use this answer as a reference and make sure your API key is set-up alike.
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/58889999/11023871)

Comment: Yes it is correct, now I am using second approach with same API key and it works fine. but using a separate config component results 403 error.

Comment: Does printing `config` inside `handleQuery`, after setting `params` give you something like the edit in the answer?

Comment: I printed the config in console and  I don't get its object. This time the url is a bet precise.

Comment: xhr.js:178 GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&key=AIzaSyCzI3MnEQsoAKyFFzqaDgb2QM7wde3ZqSo&q=Tesla 403

Comment: I would check that:
1. On Google Credentials, your API key does not have `Application restrictions` enabled. Disable if not.
2. Check that you export the correct config. Your `youtube.js` file should only have the config object I provided and Key. Then, you should explicitly import it using `{ config }` for it to work.

Try these and tell me if it helps

Comment: If it still doesn't work, please add an EDIT to your question and add your new code and what you tried.