# Getting, HttpError 403 when tried to call YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have an API token, which I've embedded into the YT API function call. However, I'm still receiving  an error 403 response. The function is directly copied from Google's GitHub website under *search.py*.

```python
DEVELOPER_KEY = 'my_token_here'
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = 'v3'

def youtube_search():
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
  # query term.
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    #q=options.q,
    part='id,snippet',
    #maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()

  videos = []
  channels = []
  playlists = []

  # Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
  # matching videos, channels, and playlists.
  for search_result in search_response.get('items', []):
    if search_result['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video':
      videos.append('%s (%s)' % (search_result['snippet']['title'],
                                 search_result['id']['videoId']))
    elif search_result['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#channel':
      channels.append('%s (%s)' % (search_result['snippet']['title'],
                                   search_result['id']['channelId']))
    elif search_result['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#playlist':
      playlists.append('%s (%s)' % (search_result['snippet']['title'],
                                    search_result['id']['playlistId']))

  print('Videos:\n', '\n'.join(videos), '\n')
  print('Channels:\n', '\n'.join(channels), '\n')
  print('Playlists:\n', '\n'.join(playlists), '\n')
```

When calling the `youtube_search` function, I am getting this error:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&key='my_token'=json returned "Requests to this API youtube method youtube.api.v3.V3DataSearchService.List are blocked.". Details: "[{'message': 'Requests to this API youtube method youtube.api.v3.V3DataSearchService.List are blocked.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]">
```

Comment: "Requests to this API are blocked" -> you probably have to go to the page where you got your API key from, and change the restrictions that the API key has. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411632/error-403-forbidden-whith-youtube-api-v3